# Select by index value in multindex DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame in this form, where place and source are indexes.
How can I select by value in the place index?

```
               Count
place     source 
market  A         5
        D         4
        B         3
ecomm   A         7
        C         6
        B         4
```

I tried :

```
df_t[df_t.index.place=="market"]
```

But I got error.

This is desired result:

```
market      A         5
            D         4
            B         3
```

Comment: Did you try `df_t.loc['market']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need `market` level in output use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with `drop_level` parameter:

```
df1 = df_t.xs('market', drop_level=False)
```

Your solution is possible modify by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
df1 = df_t[df_t.index.get_level_values('place')=="market"]

print (df1)
               Count
place  source       
market A           5
       D           4
       B           3
```

---

If need remove this level, so no `MultiIndex` in output remove `drop_level`, because default value is `drop_level = True` or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2 = df_t.xs('market')
```

---

```
df2 = df_t.loc['market']

print (df2)
        Count
source       
A           5
D           4
B           3
```